# OpenGL rendering affects CPU

Tags: performance, cpu, opengl, rendering

I have a problem with an app that is slowed down significantly when an openFrameworks based app is launched. Both apps use little cpu and memory, so i don't think there's a bottleneck.

I can reproduce the problem by running

```
openssl speed
```

alone compared to

```
openssl speed
```

in one console and

```
glmark2 -b jellyfish
```

in another.

So openGL rendering somehow affects the CPU performance and it is not clear to me why.

Can someone explain ?

(System is Ubuntu 14.04 i7 with intel HD3000, however a system with an Nvdia card showed the same effect)

Comment: It sounds like the device drivers your using do not fully support `OpenGL (ES) 2.0`

Comment: I installed the driver from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux which is the best I can get I guess. Any way to test if it supports OpenGL 2.0 ?